# Formatting Django web app for 1024x768

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am currently formatting my Django web application using Twitter Bootstrap, but things start getting weird when I resize the browser.

Ideally, I would like to keep the same format regardless of browser size, and if they go too small, than just a horizontal scroll is introduced:

If the screen resolution is 1024x768, I want the site to look good (using the full width of the screen, no warping or adjustments of image files, no horizontal scroll). If the display is wider than 1024px, there are blank space on either size. If narrower than 1024px, a horizontal scroll is introduced.

I was wondering what the best way to go about this is. Is there a way with Twitter Bootstrap? I was also thinking of putting everything into a border-less table with defined widths and centering the table on the screen? Hoping then things inside the table wouldn't resize down.

Comment: You probably better use the *responsive* features of bootstrap: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Comment: This is purely client-side (happens entirely in the browser) and thus completely unrelated to Django.